# Knight Tour using backtracking

Tags: c++, stack, backtracking, knights-tour

I am developing a program for knight tour in c++ using backtracking
Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Stack
{
public:
    Stack(int len = 100)
    {
        length = len;
        sp = -1;
        a = new T [length];
    }

    int getLength()
    {
        return length;
    }

    void push(T v)
    {
        if(isFull())
        {
            throw std::exception("Stack Overflow!");
            return;
        }
        a[++sp] = v;
    }
    bool isFull()
    {
        if(sp < getLength()-1)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
    T pop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw std::exception("Stack Underflow!");
        }
        return a[sp--];
    }
    bool isEmpty()
    {
        if(sp == -1)
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    T getTop()
    {
        if(isEmpty())
        {
            throw std::exception("Stack Underflow!");
        }
        return a[sp];
    }

private:
    T * a;
    int sp;
    int length;

};

class MoveStk
{
public:
    MoveStk()
    {
        set(0,0,0);
    }

    MoveStk(int r , int c , int d)
    {
        set(r,c,d);
    }

    void set(int r , int c , int d)
    {
        row = r;
        col = c;
        dir = d;
    }

    void get(int& r , int & c , int & d)
    {
        r = row;
        c = col;
        d = dir;
    }

private:
    int row , col , dir;
};

class Position
{
public:
    int x , y;
    Position(int i = 0 , int j = 0)
    {
        x = i;
        y = j;
    }
};


bool move(Position pos[],int posLen,int ** chess ,int n, int col, int row , int&newRow , int & newCol , int moveNo )
{
    if (row+pos[moveNo].x>=0 && row+pos[moveNo].x<n && col+pos[moveNo].y>=0 && col+pos[moveNo].y<n && chess[row+pos[moveNo].x][col+pos[moveNo].y] == 0 )
    {
        newRow = row+pos[moveNo].x;
        newCol = col+pos[moveNo].y;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main()
{

    int n = 8;

    //create stack
    Stack<MoveStk> myStack(100);



    //create dynamic array
    int ** chess = new int* [n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        chess[i] = new int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
            chess[i][j] = 0;

    //setup moves
    Position pos[8];

    pos[0] = Position(-2,1);
    pos[1] = Position(-2,-1);
    pos[2] = Position(2,1);
    pos[3] = Position(2,-1);
    pos[4] = Position(-1,-2);
    pos[5] = Position(-1,2);
    pos[6] = Position(1,2);
    pos[7] = Position(1,-2);


    //input for start (must be optional) :
    int row = 4;
    int col = 3;


    int count = 1 , moveChoose = 0;
    int newCol , newRow;

    MoveStk temp(row,col,0);//adding first move to stack
    myStack.push(temp);

    chess[row][col] = count;

    while(count<=(n*n) && !myStack.isEmpty())
    {
        temp = myStack.getTop();
        temp.set(row,col,moveChoose);

        while(moveChoose<8 && !move(pos,8,chess,n,col,row,newRow,newCol,moveChoose))//avalin khoone azad baray karkat
        {
            moveChoose++;
        }

        if(moveChoose != 8)//there is somewhere we can go
        {
            myStack.pop();
            temp.set(col,row,moveChoose+1);//adding next possible move for returning back
            myStack.push(temp);
            chess[newRow][newCol] = ++count;
            temp.set(newRow,newCol,0);
            myStack.push(temp);
        }
        else//we must return
        {
            myStack.pop();
            chess[newRow][newCol] = 0;
            count--;
        }

    }

    printArray(chess);

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

The problem is , this app only works for first moves and my stack gets empty before ending game.
I can't find where is wrong?!

What can the problem be?

Comment: What has debugging told you?

Comment: @Angew I cound not find the problem by debugging the app...

Comment: Try printing out your `row`, `col`, `moveChoose`, `push` and `pop` events to see if your recursion is working the way you think it ought to...

Comment: You need to reset moveChoose to 0 at the top of each loop.

Comment: @Trenin:  I suspect that's a horrible idea.

Comment: @JoeZ Why do you think that?  It is set to 0 before the loop, and then only ever incremented.  As soon as it is incremented the first time, it will never attempt move 0 again!

Comment: @Trenin:  What happens when you pop and you need to pick up where you left off at a given node?  You don't want to start back at 0.  You'll always re-evaluate the same exit from the same position in the recursion repeatedly, without examining other potential exits.  You need to re-set `MoveChoose`, but not to 0.

Comment: Ok - you are right.  But moveChoose still needs to be reset somewhere.  Probably in the else clause to the check for !=8

Comment: If I understood the code correctly, `moveChoose` is getting pushed.  It should also then get popped.  When using standard containers to implement a stack, this is done by examining `top()` before doing a `pop()`.  I didn't want to just give an answer, but rather guide in the direction of teaching how to debug.  And yes, after a `push`, you should reset it to 0 for the new node.

Comment: @JoeZ I could not understand what you mean bu examine top() before pop()

Comment: @Trenin That pop will just remove one item from stack

Comment: @Arashdn : At least when you use standard containers, `pop()` destroys the item on the top of stack.  The `top()` method lets you examine the top of stack before the `pop()`.  When backing out of a recursion, you need to examine the top of stack, get the details you need out of it (the row, column and next movement direction), and _then_ `pop()`.  If you `pop()` first, those details are gone, and examining top-of-stack will give you the item below that.

Comment: @Arashdn : Note that I say "when using standard containers."  Your `pop()` function returns top of stack, but you're not doing anything with it.  You're throwing it away.

Comment: BTW, have you considered just writing a code-recursive version of the function, rather than data-recursive?  They're much easier to get right.

Comment: @JoeZ - Agreed.  Recursion would be easier to do, and then adapt to a stack later if needed.

Comment: @JoeZ , I have been working on this method for many hours , so I really want to make it work .....

Comment: @Arashdn :  You should be able to write a code-recursive function, and then instrument it with `cout << ...` statements to see what it does.  Then come back to your data-recursive function above and instrument it similarly.  Where their outputs differ will suggest where your errors are.  By "code recursive", I mean a function that calls itself recursively; the compiler handles the recursion stack for you.  By "data recursive", I mean what you have now:  A loop, a stack data structure, and explicit push/pop operations.

Answer (score 2):

First, I think you need to change the lines:

```
while(count<=(n*n) && !myStack.isEmpty())
{
    temp = myStack.getTop();
    temp.set(row,col,moveChoose);
```

To:

```
while(count<=(n*n) && !myStack.isEmpty())
{
    temp = myStack.getTop();
    temp.get(row,col,moveChoose);
```

As it currently stands, you are over-writing the last move and position every time through the loop.  What you should be doing is start from where you left off by trying the next move from the previous position.

Also, I noticed you had the parameters wrong to the set call later:

```
        temp.set(col,row,moveChoose+1);//adding next possible move for returning back
```

It should be `row` then `col`.

Comment: Thanks for answer , Now it's working for about 55 moves ... But not all of them. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight%27s_tour.  This is a *difficult* problem for brute force.  You need to implement heuristics to prune the search.